# how to change a json array in to another format

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON array and I need to change that into another array format. Please look into the following array,

My array is,

```
Array{
BUS NO.1:
Array{
0:{trip: "Trip00011", runningKm: "5000"}
1:{trip: "Trip00012", runningKm: "2565"}},

BUS NO.2:
Array{
0:{trip: "Trip00021", runningKm: "2400"}
1:{trip: "Trip00023", runningKm: "1500"}
2:{trip: "Trip00025", runningKm: "3000"}}
```

}

I need,

```
data :[{y:BUS NO.1, "Trip00011": "5000","Trip00012":"2565"},
    {y:BUS NO.2, "Trip00021": "2400","Trip00023":"1500","Trip00025":"3000"},
```

Comment: are you  using php?

Comment: yes, php and jquery

Comment: then you need to add php tag also, shall i do in php

Comment: sure, you can proceed

Comment: Pls paste your orginal json data

Comment: or please atleast format your array in a correct and usable way (JSON).

Comment: This is not a JSON. Can you please format it by using any online JSON formatter?

Comment: My php array is,
Array
([0] => Array([vehicle] => BUS NO.1
            [trip_name] => Trip00011
            [running_km] => 5000)
[1] => Array([vehicle] => BUS NO.2
            [trip_name] => Trip00021
            [running_km] => 2400)
[2] => Array([vehicle] => BUS NO.2
            [trip_name] => Trip00023
            [running_km] => 1500))
And i need this as jquery response array like,
data :[{y:BUS NO.1, "Trip00011": "5000"},
  {y:BUS NO.2, "Trip00021": "2400","Trip00023":"1500"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. You'll only need 1 loop and an array_merge.

```
$originalData = [
    [
        'vehicle' => 'BUS NO.1',
        'trip_name' => 'Trip00011', 
        'running_km' => '5000'
    ],
    [
        'vehicle' => 'BUS NO.2',
        'trip_name' => 'Trip00021', 
        'running_km' => '2400'
    ],
    [
        'vehicle' => 'BUS NO.2',
        'trip_name' => 'Trip00023', 
        'running_km' => '1500'
    ],
];

$responseData = [];

foreach ($originalData as $od){
    $temp = [
        'y' => $od['vehicle'],
    ];

    $temp[$od['trip_name']] = $od['running_km'];

    if (!isset($responseData[$od['vehicle']])){
        $responseData[$od['vehicle']] = $temp;  
    } else {
        $responseData[$od['vehicle']] = array_merge($responseData[$od['vehicle']], $temp);
    }
}

echo json_encode(array_values($responseData));
```

Output (JSON): `[{"y":"BUS NO.1","Trip00011":"5000"},{"y":"BUS NO.2","Trip00021":"2400","Trip00023":"1500"}]`

Comment: Thank you @KrishnaJonnalagadda. To be honest i learned a few stuff while doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

use `lodashjs`!
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#forEach

```
const busData = {
    bus1:[
        {trip: "Trip00011", runningKm: "5000"},
        {trip: "Trip00012", runningKm: "2565"}
    ],
    bus2:[
        {trip: "Trip00021", runningKm: "2400"},
        {trip: "Trip00023", runningKm: "1500"},
        {trip: "Trip00025", runningKm: "3000"}
    ]
}

const busInfoAll = []
_.forEach(busData, (busList, busNo) => {
    const busInfo = {y: busNo};
    busList.forEach((bus) => {
        busInfo[bus.trip] = bus.runningKm;
    });
    busInfoAll.push(busInfo);
});

console.log(busInfoAll);
```